# dynamical operator javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to choose dynamicaly an operator

do something like this:

```
     var ​val1="1",
         val2="1",
         oper="===";
     if(val1 oper val2){
         console.log("im in"); 
     }else{
         console.log("im out");       
     }
```

Comment: No. (everything else I type is to fulfill the min. character limit). Let's NOT talk about eval().

Comment: If you create an operator -> function map, then yes. `eval` is an option if you have control over the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do a dynamic operator, but you can achieve the same thing using functions instead.

```
var ​val1 = "1",
    val2 = "1",
    oper = function(a, b) { return a === b; };

 if(oper(val1, val2)) {
     console.log("im in"); 
 } else {
     console.log("im out");       
 }
```

Comment: nice approach your doing that's definitly one possibility

Answer (score 1):

No javascript syntax allows that. You can generate string with js code and use `eval`, but you'd better not use eval at all.